# Can I use same APEX controller for both VF page and it's embedded lightning component to share variables?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components

I may not be right. But just as a thought, Is there a way that we can use the same APEX controller for VF page and lightning component persistently, which I can use to communicate between VF and lightning?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the same controller class but cannot share data via the controller fields. Lightning Components do not support the view state mechanism that is used in Visualforce (as that design approach tends to lead to unnecessary data being moved to and from the client).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you could use the same controller. However, you'd want to add methods that were `@AuraEnabled` to allow the communication to occur with your Lightning Components.

In practice, I think you'll want to keep the two as separate controllers. You'd also want to keep them separate for the sake of reusability. You'll find that many of your components can be used in other places beyond just the page you originally created them for.